# ItemsControl ItemsSource lazy loading

Tags: wpf, lazy-loading, selector, itemscontrol, itemsource

Image you are creating a custom control behaving like `ComboBox` in WPF.
As a source of items you provide `IQueryable<T>` (or any kind of `IEnumerable` collection),
but you don't want to allow the control to call `GetIterator()` and iterate through it (some kind of a lazy loading).

Let's say you inherit from the (because you want all the funcionality of that control)

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector
```

class.
The Selector class inherits from System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl class which provides a the well known dependency property ItemsSource.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ItemsControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsControl control = (ItemsControl) d;
    IEnumerable oldValue = (IEnumerable) e.OldValue;
    IEnumerable newValue = (IEnumerable) e.NewValue;
    ItemValueStorageField.ClearValue(d);
    if ((e.NewValue == null) && !BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, ItemsSourceProperty))
    {
        control.Items.ClearItemsSource();
    }
    else
    {
        control.Items.SetItemsSource(newValue); // PROBLEM
    }
    control.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

If I see it correctly, this is the place where it iterates.

```
internal void SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
{
    if ((!this.IsUsingItemsSource && (this._internalView != null)) && (this._internalView.RawCount > 0))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("CannotUseItemsSource"));
    }
    this._itemsSource = value;
    this._isUsingItemsSource = true;
    this.SetCollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView(this._itemsSource, this.ModelParent));
}
```

So I've decided to override metadata of ItemsSourceProperty and point it to my own static method,
where I'm planing not co call `SetItemsSource` (rather delay it).

How should it be done in your opinion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to probably add a new dependency property, say `DelayedItemsSource` of type `IEnumerable`. Then you could bind `ItemsSource` to `DelayedItemsSource` after your delay.